# Haskell prime number generator error

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, primes

I tried:

```
composites=[c|c<-[4..], any (\p->(c`mod`p == 0)) (takeWhile (< (sqrt c)) primes)]
primes=2:[p|p<-[3..], not p `elem` (takeWhile (<p) composites)]
```

and got:

```
pad.hs:1:19:
    No instance for (Num Bool) arising from the literal `4'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num Bool)
    In the expression: 4
    In the expression: [4 .. ]
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: c <- [4 .. ]

pad.hs:1:30:
    No instance for (Integral Bool) arising from a use of `divisible'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Integral Bool)
    In the first argument of `any', namely `(divisible c)'
    In the expression: any (divisible c) (factors c)
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: any (divisible c) (factors c)

pad.hs:3:43:
    No instance for (Floating Bool) arising from a use of `sqrt'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Floating Bool)
    In the second argument of `(<)', namely `sqrt c'
    In the first argument of `takeWhile', namely `(< sqrt c)'
    In the expression: takeWhile (< sqrt c) primes
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I think that it is confused as to what type of number it is dealing with, but I am not sure. Any tips?

Comment: Even with the fixes from `leftaroundabout`s answer, you'd still not get the result you're hoping for. To see why, consider how your `primes` could ever not be just the list `[3..]` unfiltered. You also make that error in generating `composites`

Comment: in both `takeWhile` calls it should be `<=`, not `<`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think that it is confused as to what type of number it is dealing with

Quite right! So why don't you tell it? It's always a good idea to write the function signature in Haskell, before the actual implementation. Not only does this prevent such confusing compiler messages when something's wrong, it also makes up a really good guide in actually designing the function.

So in your case, you probably want<sup>1</sup>

```
composites, primes :: [Integer]
```

which of course doesn't solve the problem, but it makes the error messages much clearer:

> Prelude> let composites,primes::[Integer]; composites=[c|c<-[4..], any (\p -> c`mod`p == 0) (takeWhile (< sqrt c) primes)]; primes=2:[p|p<-[3..], not p `elem` (takeWhile (< p) composites)]
>   
> <‌interactive>:2:128:
>       Couldn't match expected type `Integer' with actual type `Bool'
>       In the expression: p
>       In the second argument of `(:)', namely
>         `[p | p <- [3 .. ], not p `elem` (takeWhile (< p) composites)]'
>       In the expression:
>         2 : [p | p <- [3 .. ], not p `elem` (takeWhile (< p) composites)]
>   
>   <‌interactive>:2:169:
>       Couldn't match type `Integer' with `Bool'
>       Expected type: [Bool]
>         Actual type: [Integer]
>       In the second argument of `takeWhile', namely `composites'
>       In the second argument of `elem', namely
>         `(takeWhile (< p) composites)'
>       In the expression: not p `elem` (takeWhile (< p) composites)

It's still not exactly to the point, but at least it now localises the error to where it is: in `primes`, `p` is inferred to be `Bool`, which is of course wrong. The reason for bool is that you have `` not p `elem` (...) `` in there. Evidently you think this is parsed as `` not (p`elem`(...)) ``, but it's not: plain prefix function application has higher precedence than any infix operator. An important thing to know (that's also why you don't need parens around `sqrt c` in `(< sqrt c)`).

Let's fix that, then there remains one more problem:

> Prelude> let composites,primes::[Integer]; composites=[c|c<‌-[4..], any (\p->(c`mod`p == 0)) (takeWhile (<‌ (sqrt c)) primes)]; primes=2:[p|p<‌-[3..], not $ p `elem` (takeWhile (<‌p) composites)]
>   
>   <‌interactive>:3:99:
>       No instance for (Floating Integer) arising from a use of `sqrt'
>       Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Floating Integer)
>       In the second argument of `(<‌)', namely `(sqrt c)'
>       In the first argument of `takeWhile', namely `(<‌ (sqrt c))'
>       In the second argument of `any', namely
>         `(takeWhile (<‌ (sqrt c)) primes)'

Now that is spot on: you're dealing with integer numbers, but `sqrt` obviously yields generally irrational numbers, so it only makes sense with a `Floating` type. To get around this, you can use the (admittedly ugly, but ok) `sqrt' = round . sqrt . fromIntegral`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, this monomorphic signature is probably not ideal – you might prefer `Int` for various reasons (mainly efficiency). To be on the safe side, one would choose  `Integral a => [a]`; however polymorphic values aren't "memoised" at the top level which is again quite a problem in this example.

Answer (score 1):

> Any tips?

Well, now that you got it fixed,

```
composites=[c|c<-[4..], any ((==0).(c`mod`)) (takeWhile ((<= c).(^2)) primes)]
primes=2:[p|p<-[3..], not (p `elem` takeWhile (<= p) composites)]
```

consider whether you can make it faster. For one thing, `elem` fully consumes its second argument when the 1st isn't present in it, and always searches from the start. But if we've just searched for ***16*** among the composites, there's no need to start over when we search for ***17*** next - we can continue on from the same point:

```
notAmong (_, (k:ks,c:cs))              -- a candidate that is not among
   | k == c    = (Nothing, (ks,cs))    --     the composites, is a prime
   | otherwise = (Just k, (ks,c:cs))   -- (k < c)
primes = 2 : [p | (Just p,_) <- iterate notAmong (Just 3, ([4..],composites))]
```

We've *fused* the functions `not`, `elem` and `takewhile`, with great benefit speedwise.

Try to find out this version's [empirical orders of growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) and compare with the original version, it's fun.

Comment: How I did it was I fused together primes and composites.

Comment: @PyRulez does your version run at *`~ n^1.30..1.45`* (in *`n`* primes produced)?

Comment: depends, will ghc cache any values it finds in a list, or will it recalculate the values each time it is needed?

Comment: @PyRulez you could just measure it empirically. The link is in the answer. :)